# integrate file generated by ireport with flex project examples

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, jasper-reports, ireport

i have implemented a J2EE project using (Flex, Spring, hibernate), but, in this project i have to add functionnality of reporting, so i decided to work with iReport.

How do you integrate a "file" generated by iReport to the J2EE project?

Where can I find tutorials that explain how to use iReport files with Flex to implement reporting functionality?